# turning column headers into observations pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm not sure if my issue has a specific name (I remember listening to a lecture where the teacher said that a portion of knowledge is knowing the name of things).

Anyway, I'm working with some legacy systems and my data is output as the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Shop' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],'Week 1' : [15,25,11,22,0,-1,15,11,76,62],'Week 2' : [5,44,55,21,12,51,-10,25,81,46]})
print(df)


 Shop   Week 1  Week 2
0   1   15      5
1   2   25      44
2   3   11      55
3   4   22      21
4   5   0       12
5   6   -1      51
6   7   15     -10
7   8   11      25
8   9   76      81
9   10  62      46
```

In this instance, the week number should be an observation and the number is an value that should be assigned to it.

what I'm trying to do is the following.

transpose the DF but keep the index as the Shop.
turn each instance into an observation so taking only the first 2 shops as an example:

```
    Shop    Week Hour
0   1       1    15
1   1       2    5
2   2       1    25
3   2       2    44
```

What would be the most pythonic way to achieve this? on a relatively medium sized df (500 rows 52 weeks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rename columns, [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) and then [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df.columns = [i if not i.startswith('Week') else int(i[-1]) for i in df]

res = pd.melt(df, id_vars='Shop', var_name='Week', value_name='Hour')\
        .sort_values('Shop').reset_index(drop=True)

print(res)

    Shop Week  Hour
0      1    1    15
1      1    2     5
2      2    1    25
3      2    2    44
...
16     9    2    81
17     9    1    76
18    10    1    62
19    10    2    46
```

Comment: perfect! inspecting the data : )

Answer (score 3):

Using `wide_to_long`

```
pd.wide_to_long(df,'Week ',i='Shop',j='week')
Out[770]: 
           Week 
Shop week       
1    1        15
2    1        25
3    1        11
4    1        22
5    1         0
6    1        -1
7    1        15
8    1        11
9    1        76
10   1        62
1    2         5
2    2        44
3    2        55
4    2        21
5    2        12
6    2        51
7    2       -10
8    2        25
9    2        81
10   2        46

#pd.wide_to_long(df,'Week ',i='Shop',j='week').sort_index(level=0).reset_index().rename(columns={'Week ':'Hour'})
```

Comment: like sacul's my shop is an int, so i='Shop' threw an error!  'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int

Comment: @Datanovice I am using your sample did to produce this what is error?

Comment: your code is flawless, i was using a sql data dump. thanks for your help good sir.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this, though it's a bit messy with all the re-naming:

```
# Rename columns with dict comprehension so it can extend to more than week 1 and week 2
df2 = (df.rename(columns={i: int(i.split()[-1]) for i in df.columns[1:]})
       .set_index('Shop')
       .stack()
       .reset_index()
       .rename(columns={'level_1':'Week', 0:'Hour'}))

>>> df2

    Shop  Week  Hour
0      1     1    15
1      1     2     5
2      2     1    25
3      2     2    44
4      3     1    11
5      3     2    55
6      4     1    22
7      4     2    21
8      5     1     0
9      5     2    12
10     6     1    -1
11     6     2    51
12     7     1    15
13     7     2   -10
14     8     1    11
15     8     2    25
16     9     1    76
17     9     2    81
18    10     1    62
19    10     2    46
```

Comment: would you go and rename each week assuming there are 52 in my DF?

Comment: I don't see why not, it should be a fast operation

Comment: almost worked, my shop's dtype is as an int so the split threw an error, jpp's code worked flawlessly for me. in the instance above would changing the dtype work with your code above?

Comment: I'm not sure how `Shop`'s dtype would affect the code above (it's int in my interpreter as well). But if it's about the column renaming, then you could use something like what jpp did, and only rename the columns that start with `Week`...

Comment: I'm most likely not using the code correctly, it worked perfectly on my sample DF. thanks for the answer.